# How to make infinite scroll view in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I have a `scrollview` with **5 image views of width 88**.

I want the `scrollview` to scroll to each image view **(Not Paging)**

**and**

I want to make **an infinite scrollview in iPhone** which means the when it scroll to last item it will display a first item next to it..

I have been trying by offset but it stops when move it by offset and also **I have used apple street scroller which does not allow me to stop each element in center(just like Picker view)..**

Comment: is it going to be with or without user interaction?

Comment: https://github.com/canopas/MarqueeScroll

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, I recommend to use a UITableView so you can maintain the memory usage low. An approach that I had used successfully in a project is the following:

  1. List item

Duplicate the content of your cells, I mean if you have 5 items in this way:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

You should add the same (In a table view with reusable engine that's not a big deal) at the end of the table in order to look like this:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

  2. modify the scrollViewDidScroll with the following:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == _yourScrollView) {
        CGFloat currentOffsetX = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
        CGFloat currentOffSetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        CGFloat contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;

        if (currentOffSetY < (contentHeight / 6.0f)) {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(currentOffsetX,(currentOffSetY + (contentHeight/2)));
        }
        if (currentOffSetY > ((contentHeight * 4)/ 6.0f)) {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(currentOffsetX,(currentOffSetY - (contentHeight/2)));
        }
    }
}
```

The code above move the scroll position at top if you almost reach the final of the scrolling; Or if you are almost on the top, moves you to the bottom...

  3. That's it.

Comment: Great solution. However is there any way to omit this 'blink' when offset is changed?

Answer (score 8):

You can have a look at one of this two options:

- If you are registered as a developer, watch the session **Advanced ScrollView Techniques** from WWDC 2011.
- A great tutorial from http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html

Comment: Advanced Scrollview Techniques is *the* thing to watch to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

This caused me serious problems for a long time so I really feel your pain. I found this control which should solve your problem: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/infinitescrollview

I also considered inserting transitions and disabled scroll so it becomes like a slideshow but either way should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short explanation of solution I used to do it.

Lets say you have counter from 0 - 9, then, when you make transition 9 -> 0, you actually spoof another 0 (call it 0') after 9 (in scrollView), make animated transition to 0' and than make non-animated instant transition to 0 that stands on top of scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **iCarousel** library for this.
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else looking for a solution, you can also try this library Infinite Scroll Picker at https://github.com/Seitk/InfiniteScrollPicker/ It's basically drag and drop.  I'm using it on a project and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented a simple infinity scroll in this mini project:

https://github.com/mcmatan/Infinity-tabBar-scroll-view/blob/master/README.md